# NSTextView: auto-completion for "."-prefix words

Tags: swift, autocomplete, nstextview

I want to provide auto-completion for "words" like `.abc` as well as `def.abc` and `abc` as way to refer to significant tokens in a NSTextView.

I'm able to get the `def.abc` and the `abc` cases working, but the "."-prefixed `.abc` is not working. I'm using `textView(_:completions:forPartialWordRange:indexOfSelectedItem:)`
 delegate method of `NSTextViewDelegate.`

In the `.abc` case, the auto-completion mechanism in NSTextView inserts the ".abc" completion after the "." and results in `..abc` -- which is impractical.

I've looked at the documentation of `NSTextView` and `NSTextViewDelegate` and can not find a way to make the auto-completion work in such `.abc` case, avoiding the `..abc` result — e.g. replacing the initial "." by "" by hooking into a `didSelectCompletion` delegate method.

Any hints?

Answer (score 2):

How about overriding `rangeForUserCompletion` in NSTextView to expand range so that `.` is included?

Comment: It's a possibility. I'll give it a try and post here the result.

Comment: Can confirm that overriding `rangeForUserCompletion` fixes that issue.  

I also had the problem that period and spacebar were both acting as an "accept completion" action rather than being entered as plain characters.  To work around that I had to override `insertCompletion:forPartialWordRange:movement:isFinal`, and skip out if isFinal and `NSApp.currentEvent` was a keyDown for one of those characters.